# Why won't my code find a period after typing the sentence?

Tags: java, string

Why won't my code find a period after typing the sentence? The user is supposed to write a sentence and then put a period at the end. When the period is entered then the program should end. Help?

```
import java.io.*;
class Sentence



{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
BufferedReader mVHS = new BufferedReader (inStream);

String inData; //Store the input data in a String    
int result;//Assign the result to the int data type
String sentence, string2; //Store the names in the String type



//Enter a sentance
System.out.println("Type a sentence but make sure it ends with a period:");
Sting userInput = mVHS.readLine();
sentence = userInput;


while(sentence.length()){
    { 

   if(sentence.equals("."))
        System.out.println("Thank you come again.");
   else
    System.out.println("You must put a period to end the program");
    System.out.println("Type a period:");
    userInput = mVHS.readLine();
    sentence = userInput;
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: if(sentence.equals(".")) checks whether the sentence contains only a ".". It fails when sentence is "how are you . ". use String#matches("\.$"); or String#endsWith(".")

Comment: Does this code compile?

Comment: I'm not a java programmer, so I could be very wrong here, but it looks to me like you're relying on a built in input function that is entered by pressing the return key rather than a function that inputs each letter one at a time until a period is pressed? Or does the while loop run asymmetrically at the same time as the user input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while(sentence.length()){
    { 

   if(sentence.equals("."))
```

the while statement has an invalid expression in it.
and: sentence.equals(".") will only return true, if you entered nothing but .

you can check: if sentence.endsWith(".");

Comment: Ok now I get an error on the while loop saying it requires a boolean type but it found an int

Comment: You are checking whether or not the length of sentence == true. change the statement in your while to be while(sentence.length == 1) or some other boolean expression

Comment: This still does not loop the program :/

Comment: of course it doesn't.
you can always create a charArray from your String, and iterate over it's elements.